# Delete null values from Json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

for a multilevel nested Json what will be the approach to delete all the null values retaining the other data

```
json = {
    "Object": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "23",
        "Des": "SE",
        "tech": {
            "Primary": ".net",
            "secondary": "java",
            "current": {
                "first": "Angular",
                "second": "Spring",
                "interests": {
                    "First": "FED",
                    "Second": null,
                    "value": {
                        "First": "High",
                        "Second": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please assist me on this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a recursive approach? You could have a function that modifies a dictionary by dropping keys with `None` values and recursing into `dict`-values.

Comment: @Manfred Thanks for the suggestion will try that out!

Comment: @Manfred your comment should probably be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to build a dictionary basically containing all `key: value` items where `value != None`, which recurses into `dict` values.
A *dict comprehension* allows to encode it as a single statement:

```py
def remove_null_values(d: dict) -> dict:
    return {
        key: remove_null_values(value) if isinstance(value, dict) else value
        for key, value in d.items()
        if value != None
    }
```